# Terminal commands equivalent to NetworkManager's "Use as Hotspot" option

Tags: networking, iptables, wifi, internet, networkmanager

I'm making a gui application which will control my laptop in order to make it act as a wifi hotspot. I may change distributions so I want to find a solution which will work generally for all distributions. I am currently doing this on Fedora 17.

Using NetworkManager's "Use as Hotspot" button works very well to create an ad-hoc hotspot:
[image]

I want to recreate this functionality with terminal commands.


Below are two methods I tried to accomplish this but I havn't found a solution yet.

---

**Method 1: iwconfig**

Using research from accross the web, I tried the following command:

```
# ifconfig wlan0 10.42.0.1 netmask 255.555.255.0 broadcast 10.42.0.255 up
# iwconfig wlan0 essid my-lappy mode ad-hoc key 0123456789
# iptables-restore < saved-hotspot-iptables
# echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
# dhclient wlan0
```

where `saved-hotspot-iptables` is a file which I generated with `iptables-save > saved-hotspot-iptables` with the iptables set by the "Use as Hotspot" function.

**Method 1 Problem**

Devices can see the SSID but are unable to connect. Running `ip a` reveals the following about wlan0:

```
...
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DORMANT qlen 1000
...
```

Notice `NO-CARRIER` is present, and the state is `DORMANT` instead of `UP`.

Running `ifconfig wlan0` shows the following:

```
...
wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
...
```

Notice that `RUNNING` is missing as one of the flags.

---

**Method 2: nmcli**

If NetworkManager's "Use as Hotspot" button is pressed at least once on the system, `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-Hotspot` is created and I can use the following command to start a working hotspot:

```
# ifconfig wlan0 up
# nmcli con up id Hotspot
# iwconfig wlan0 essid my-lappy key 0123456789
```

**Method 2 Problem**

If the user has never pressed "Use as Hotspot" on NetworkManager before, `nmcli con up id Hotspot` won't work. I've looked at `nm-connection-editor --create` but couldn't find much information. I've also looked into manually creating `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-Hotspot` but this method does not seem elegant or extendible to other distributions.

Comment: Please don't [crosspost](http://serverfault.com/q/401355/115189).

Comment: Try [wicd](http://wicd.sourceforge.net/). It is similar to NetworkManager but has a text mode interface. I don't know if it has a hotspot feature.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Gilles, I'm going to try it out right away.

Comment: @Gilles I tried wicd but it appears to have even less functionality then nmcli.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a dedicated option in `nmcli`:

```
nmcli device wifi hotspot ifname wlan0 ssid toto password toto
```

More info from the [Manual](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nmcli.html):

```
wifi hotspot [ifname ifname] [con-name name] [ssid SSID] [ band { a | bg } ] [channel channel] [password password]
```

Answer (score 2):

See my [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/234756/24036) to the ["Create wireless access point and share internet connection with `nmcli`"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/234552/create-wireless-access-point-and-share-internet-connection-with-nmcli/234756#234756)

I created a Hotspot with the GNOME Network-Manager. The problem was, that I can not configure the SSID and password in GUI. If you create the Hotspot with the Network-Manager GUI, it creates the file `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot`. In that file it is possible to edit the SSID and the password.

```
sudo vim /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot
```

The content of the file looks like this:

```
[connection]
id=Hotspot
uuid=0bf627gd-8e34-48c6-865a-06f898b4y1hb
type=wifi
autoconnect=false
permissions=
secondaries=

[wifi]
hidden=false
mac-address=YOUR_WIFI_INTERFACE_MAC_ADDRESS
mac-address-blacklist=
mode=ap
seen-bssids=
ssid=SSID_NAME

[wifi-security]
group=ccmp;
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
pairwise=ccmp;
proto=rsn;
psk=YOUR_WIFI_AP_PASSWORD

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=shared

[ipv6]
dns-search=
method=auto
```

I only changed the `ssid` and the `psk` properties to my needs. Then I restarted my computer because the command: `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager` for network restart seems not to work correctly, because in the Network-Manager GUI I have no wireless network settings anymore and also the following command worked not before the restart. After restart you can use the `nmcli` command to start the access point.

```
nmcli con up Hotspot ifname YOUR_WIFI_INTERFACE
```

`YOUR_WIFI_INTERFACE` you can find out with the command `iwconfig`.

Answer (score 0):

A DHCP server was needed to assign IP addresses to wifi connections. I used `dnsmasq`, a DNS and DHCP server.

The following are the commands to start an ad-hoc wifi hotspot:

```
# ifconfig wlan0 10.42.0.1 netmask 255.555.255.0 broadcast 10.42.0.255 up
# iwconfig wlan0 essid my-lappy mode ad-hoc key 0123456789
# iptables-restore < saved-hotspot-iptables
# echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
# dnsmasq -C /dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 --bind-interfaces --listen-address=10.42.0.1 --dhcp-range=10.42.0.10,10.42.0.200,12h
```