# nmcli connection activation failed

Tags: networking, command-line, networkmanager, wifi-hotspot

I was able to create a Wi-Fi hotspot on my Debian 8 install using the network tab under Gnome settings. I was trying to do the same using nmcli but when I do

```
$ nmcli con up id Hotspot
```

it always shows

> Error: Connection activation failed.

I'm trying to connect to the connection created by Gnome itself.

```
$ nmcli connection show
```

> Hotspot             6db9bb0a-c61b-47fc-8ada-7ecd46873fc0  802-11-wireless  --

I followed the steps from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41385/terminal-commands-equivalent-to-networkmanagers-use-as-hotspot-option).

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange! On my machine, I need to run `nmcli con up id` with `sudo`. Maybe that helps.

Comment: @nhee tried, but the same error.

Comment: Sorry, no idea then.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this on Arch Linux 4.19.2 because `wpa_supplicant` and `dhcpcd` were running on my system.

The fix in my case was to end those programs and restart `NetworkManager`:

```
sudo pkill wpa_supplicant && sudo pkill dhcpcd
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

After that, I can connect again:

```
nmcli con up myNetwork
```

The complete error message was

> Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection (device wlp3s0 not available because device is not available).

I think `wicd` also interferes with `NetworkManager`.